# Javascript Canvas how to scale up image

Tags: javascript, canvas, scale

I'm using the scale() function with canvas but I'm not sure how it works because it doesn't seem to work in the way you'd guess it would. I simply want to scale the image up by two.

```
const imageData = tempcanv.getContext('2d').getImageData(0, 0, tempcanv.width, tempcanv.height);
const canvas2 = document.createElement("canvas");
const ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
canvas2.width = tempcanv.width * 2, canvas2.height = tempcanv.height * 2;
ctx2.scale(2, 2);
ctx2.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

This simply makes the image inside of a bigger canvas, but the image size itself has not changed. Is this not what scale() is supposed to do or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Using `putImageData` it is not affected by the current transformations on your canvas - in your case the `scale` will not have any effect.

Instead, what you can do is use the `drawImage` function to draw your temp canvas onto your other canvas at your desired scale, e.g.:

```
...
// Syntax: ctx.drawImage(image, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);
ctx2.drawImage(tempcanv, 0, 0, tempcanv.width * 2, tempcanv.height * 2);
...
```

---

Here is a basic example drawing one canvas onto the other.

```js
var canv1 = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var canv2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');
// Draw a rect on our source canvas as an example image
canv1.getContext('2d').fillRect(1, 1, 40, 40);
// Draw our first canvas onto our second at 2x
canv2.getContext('2d').drawImage(canv1, 0, 0, canv1.width * 2, canv1.height * 2);
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="canvas1" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
</div>
<div>
  <canvas id="canvas2" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: I noticed you didn't use scale()....what exactly is scale for? I've seen other questions asking about scaling with canvas and they didn't use the scale function either. Does it exist for any purpose? I mean, why does scale have no effect? I seem to be able to all kinds of manipulations to the canvas without using drawImage, putImageData was always fine.

Comment: Do you add `canvas2` in your DOM? In your example you create it in code but don't show how it gets added to the page.

Comment: Although `scale` does not apply for the pixel data operations (`get/putImageData`) what it is for is applying a transform that affects subsequent draw functions on the canvas. In my example, I use `drawImage` with the destination width/height being 2x but you could also apply a `scale` before your `drawImage` and it would change the scale at which it is drawn.

Comment: So I could add scale() as well before the drawImage? But it's already being enlarged, what would that do in addition?

Comment: You could use it in place of drawing the image at 2x (providing the destination width and height at 2x). For example if you wanted to wanted to perform multiple draw operations at 2x you could use `scale` and then perform your drawing at the original scale (i.e `canv2.getContext('2d').drawImage(canv1, 0, 0)`) letting the transform handle the scaling. For a single image drawing it's an unnecessary step though.